# GeoCoordinateWatcher - Increase Accuracy

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates

I am starting to use the GeoCoordinateWatcher in C#. My problem is that even though I have the accuracy set to high, it is only returning 4 decimal places when I need it to return the exact coordinates which would be about 13 decimal places long. Is there any way to do this?

Below is my code, any help is appreciated :)

C#:

```
           GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
           public void GetLocationEvent()
            {
                this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                watcher.MovementThreshold = 0;
                this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
                bool started = this.watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
                if (!started)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("GeoCoordinateWatcher timed out on start.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }

            void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
            {
                PrintPosition(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
            }

            void PrintPosition(double Latitude, double Longitude)
            {
                CoordinatesLabel.Content = Latitude.ToString() + ", " + Longitude.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean with 13 decimal places? That would be about a hundreth of a micrometer in latitude and even less in longitude direction. Which sensor do you think is able to produce such data?

Comment: I honestly do not know much about coordinates... I just need something that is going to track a person as they walk.

Comment: The accuracy of the Global Positioning System is roughly five meters, when conditions are perfect. Four decimal places in latitude is about 11 meters. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: This will be used for finding the location of a meter :/ I was really hoping this was a simple issue.